# Is SQL powerful enough to do this?

Tags: sql

Our legacy app exports data into an SQL table in the following format

```
**Row#** | **Column#** | **Parameter** | **Value**
```

e.g.

```
1 | 1 | Name  | Michael

1 | 2 | Age   | 30

1 | 3 | email | email@email.com

2 | 1 | Name  | Brian

2 | 2 | Age   | 45

2 | 3 | email | brian@email.com
```

And I need to, using only SQL, return something like this

```
**Name** | **Age** | **email**

Michael  |    30   | email@email.com

Brian    |    45   | brian@email.com
```

Is this possible? If so, how? Further details:

- The number of columns and the column names ARE fixed and could be hard coded
- The number of rows is not fixed

Comment: Well, what DB does that table use? How do you access it? If it's just a program where you say: get me 10 lines, we can't do much.

Comment: Its not a matter of whether SQL (the language) is capable of this (it is). Its more a matter of which database are you exporting to as that will determine the method exact syntax

Comment: What is the purpose of the 'Column' number in your data - isn't it redundant because of the 'Parameter' column?

Comment: This is a MSSQL DB - I'm not sure why 'column' is there: this is just a feature of the exporting program.

Comment: OK, that means it ok to ignore it then : ) thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), or just some fun with aggregates:

```
SELECT
    Row#,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter='Name' THEN Value END) as Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter='Age' THEN Value END) as Age,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Parameter='email' THEN Value END) as Email
FROM
    Table
group by
    Row#
```

Exact syntax, and which option to use, will depend on what SQL database you're using

Answer (score 2):

You need a `PIVOT` or `CROSS TAB` query. Your RDBMS may have specific support for this. If not the following should work pretty much anywhere AFAIK.

```
SELECT
       MAX(CASE WHEN Column=1 then Value END) AS Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Column=2 then Value END) AS Age,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Column=3 then Value END) AS Email
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY row
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
        A.Name,
        B.Age,
        C.email
FROM
        myTable A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable B
            ON A.Row = B.Row
                AND B.Parameter = 'Age'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable C
            ON A.Row = C.Row
                AND C.Parameter = 'email'
WHERE
        A.Parameter = 'Name'
```

Continue with more table aliases as needed.  Note that if your table is very wide, this can be arduous to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

So your data is in [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) format. Thats not uncommon.

You can transfer it to tabular format with a series of joins, or a pivot operation.

See [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118051/is-sql-powerful-enough-to-do-this/5118131#5118131) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118051/is-sql-powerful-enough-to-do-this/5118109#5118109) for the SQL join methods

If you're using SQL Server, the [SQL Server PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) command to do it would look something like this:

```
    SELECT Row
    , [Name] 
    , [age] 
    , [email] 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT [Row], [Parameter], [Value]
        FROM EAV_Data
    ) p
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX ([Value])
        FOR Parameter IN ([Name], [age], [email])
    ) AS pvt
```